# AutoComplete Fragment set character threshold

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using the embedded PlaceAutocompleteFragment from google from here :
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

I need to set on the Fragment a threshold, so that it only uses  PlaceAutoComplete Api from google to search after 3 characters were input.

my fragment code xml`<fragment
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

and my java code

```
    autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS).build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
    autocompleteFragment.setHint("Suche");
    autocompleteFragment
            .setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Status status) {
            }
    });
```

Is there a way to set a threshold for the Autocomplete?
Thanks

Edit: As it seems, i havent found any ways to change something on the widget like character threshold to fire autocomplete.

There are workarounds like :
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/
with CustomAutoCompleteTextView.
The Problem i have with that is, that i cant use the Place Class from google with stored latitute,longtitude,addressname etc.